# TFMini Plus frame rate

Tags: sensor

I'm trying to make a python script to read a TFMini Lidar module, and I would like to make the readings less frequent. For that I would need to decrease the frequency.

I've been reading the TFMini Plus manual, which states that:

> Only frame rates meet the formula–1000/n (n is positive integer) can
>   be set. The default frame rate is 100Hz.

Does anyone know how to decrease TFMini Plus frame rate? I have no clue on how to make the python script to control this. I'm using a USB-to-TTL attached to a RaspberryPi 4.

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked the seller/manufacturer?  The product does not appear to be Pi specific.

Comment: Hey @joan, it isn't. I'm in contact with them already, but I was hoping any other Stack Exchange user may had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Install the `tfmplus` python module <`python -m pip install tfmplus`>. The process will also install `pyserial`, which is required.  Then get the example script `tfmp_test.py` out of the `python/lib/site-packages/tfmplus/src/tests/` folder to see how the module works.

Note: This module uses the RPi GPIO15/Rx and GPIO14/Tx to connect the TFMPlus.